# configuring a MySQL DataSource in GlassFish 3 Application Server

Tags: mysql, osx-lion, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

Does anyone know the steps for configuring a mysql datasource in glassfish 3? I am stuck on what the `datasourceName` should be. Here are the steps I have been following. Are they correct? Am I missing a step? BTW, I have glassfish `3.1.2` installed as part of `Netbeans 7.2` on `Mac OSX Lion`

- 1) Install MySQL using XAMPP
- 2) Download /jars/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22 and add to CLASSPATH
- 3) From Netbeans, start glassfish and launch `Domain Admin Console`
- 4) Go to Common Tasks > Resources > JDBC > JDBC Connection Pools and click `NEW`
- 5) Pool Name: MySQL
- Resource Type: javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
- Database Driver Vendor: MySQL
- 6) Click `Next` and scroll down to `Additional Properties (8)`
- portNumber: 3306
- databaseName: mygames // this is arbitrary
- datasourceName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver // I am not sure this is correct
- roleName:
- networkProtocol
- serverName: localhost
- user : myname
- password: mypassword
- 7) click finish.

One of the questions I still have, is there a best location to put `/jars/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22`? And how do I tell the DataSource setup how to reach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My configuration actually works. The problem I was having was placing the jar in the correct directory path. I think I found it, because it's working:

```
 /Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-3.1.2.2/glassfish/lib
```