# persistence.xml variable declaration

Tags: jpa, glassfish-3, persistence.xml

I am fairly new to JPA and in my project the applciation server is **Glassfish 3.1.2**
.So when i encountered persitence.xml in my project ,I have gone through http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Runtime to get basic idea of how it is used in JavaSE and JavaEE. 
However i came across few properties that are configured via ${}.

```
<jta-data-source>${dataSource}</jta-data-source>  
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${testDBUser}" />
```

So i am confused where these variables (dataSource,testDBUser..etc) are defined. And so i have gone through this 
http://tomee.apache.org/configuring-persistenceunits-in-tests.html  and 
http://forcedotcom.github.io/java-sdk/connection-url.
I understood that these are either system varibales and environmental variables / initial context variables.

However i do not know where they are configured/declared ,i searched my entire project for these variables but of no luck.

Are these variables are configured during the start-up of the application server / are they declared in any *.xml of the application server.

Can you please brief where these are declared?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually are declared in ***.properties*** file. Mainly, it can be named like *database.**properties***. But it is not enough to make it work. You need somehow to map it. So, Spring takes a role and offer a nice way to make it :  use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and syntax is something like this:

```
    <property name="location">
        <value>HERE DECLARE YOUR PROPERTY FILE</value>
        <value>HERE DECLARE YOUR PROPERTY FILE</value>
                      ...
    </property>
```

But the best way is to declare it in your server.xml :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Spring is not used in my project. EJB,JPA with Glassfish webserver. I checked entire project (which included .properties files as well) but i did not come across the variables.

However can you tell what is server.xml ? You mean to say application.xml in application server ?

Comment: Try to find if project has ResourceLink, also try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655842/configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-glassfish-3-application-server